# @react-google-maps/api shows loading... when the network is slow or chrome version is too low

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I have a website for rendering maps from the @react-google-maps/api library. Everything works fine but when I make the network so slow or if your chrome version is too low like around 80.xxxx it shows Loading... and the map component stucks at there like this
[image: Loading...]

And my code is this

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, InfoBox, LoadScript, Marker, useJsApiLoader } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import InfoBoxComponent from '@react-google-maps/api/dist/components/addons/InfoBox';
// other imports
export interface InsMapProps {
    markers: Mkr[];
}

const InsMap = ({ markers }: InsMapProps) => {
    const infoBoxRef = useRef<InfoBoxComponent>(null);
    const { markerId } = useMarker();
    const [isInfoBoxOpen, setIsInfoBoxOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [responseMarkers, setResponseMArkers] = useState<Mkr[]>([]);
    const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState<Mkr | null>(null);
    const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map<Element>>();
    const [zoom] = useState(14);
    const mapRef = useRef<google.maps.Map<Element>>();
    const { city, district, insType, country, searchStr } = useInsStore();
    const { ins } = useInsList();
    const [center, setcenter] = useState<TStartPoint>({
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
    });

    const apiKey = getGmapsKeys();

    const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        googleMapsApiKey: apiKey
    });

    const version = getBrowser();

    const onLoadMap = useCallback(
        (mapFromLib: google.maps.Map<Element>) => {
            mapRef.current = mapFromLib;
            setMap(mapFromLib);
        },
        [map]
    );
    const convertToNumber = (point: TStartPoint): TStartPoint => {
        const n: TStartPoint = {
            lat: parseFloat(String(point.lat)),
            lng: parseFloat(String(point.lng))
        };
        return n;
    };
    const onMarkerClick = useCallback(
        (event) => {
            setSelectedMarker(event);
            setIsInfoBoxOpen(true);
            console.log('selected marker=>', event);
        },
        [map]
    );
    const markerType = (obj: any) => {
        switch (obj.typeId) {
            case '1001':
                return Hastane;
            case '1002':
                return Eczane;
            case '1008':
                return Doktor;
            default:
                return Pin;
        }
    };
    const optionType = (obj: any, index: any) => {
        const result = {
            ...obj,
            id: obj.id,
            index
        };
        return result;
    };
    const setMarkersFunction = (insListArr: TInstitution[]) => {
        const tempMarkers: Array<Mkr> = [];

        insListArr.forEach((marker, index: any) => {
            if (marker.name.toLocaleLowerCase('tr').includes(searchStr)) {
                const _marker: Mkr = {
                    position: {
                        lng: Number(marker['lng']),
                        lat: Number(marker['lat'])
                    },
                    icon: markerType(marker),
                    zIndex: marker.selected ? 999 : 100,
                    options: optionType(marker, index)
                };
                tempMarkers.push(_marker);
            }
        });
        return tempMarkers;
    };
    const filterAll = async () => {
        const newOnes = setMarkersFunction(ins);
        setResponseMArkers([...newOnes]);
    };
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        filterAll();
    }, [district, insType, markers.length, ins, searchStr]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const canPan = selectedMarker !== null && mapRef.current;
        if (canPan) {
            mapRef.current?.panTo(selectedMarker.position);
        }
    }, [selectedMarker]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (markerId.length > 0) {
            responseMarkers.forEach((mark: Mkr) => {
                if (mark.options.id && mark.options.id === markerId) {
                    onMarkerClick(mark);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    }, [markerId]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const canSetCenter = city !== null;
        if (canSetCenter) {
            mapRef.current?.setZoom(12);
            console.log('center', center);
            setcenter({
                lat: Number(city.coorY),
                lng: Number(city.coorX)
            });
        }
    }, [city, district, country]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log({ district });
        const canSetCenter = district !== null && district.code !== '9999';
        if (canSetCenter) {
            mapRef.current?.setZoom(14);
            setcenter({
                lat: Number(district?.coorY),
                lng: Number(district?.coorX)
            });
        }
    }, [district]);

    return (
        <div className="InsMap" data-testid="InsMap" id="InsMap">
            {isLoaded ? (
                <LoadScript
                    onError={(e) => console.log('loadscript error', e)}
                    googleMapsApiKey={getGmapsKeys()}
                    language={'tr-TR'}
                >
                    <GoogleMap
                        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
                        zoom={zoom}
                        options={mapOptions}
                        onLoad={onLoadMap}
                        center={convertToNumber({ lat: center.lat, lng: center.lng })}
                        onCenterChanged={() => mapRef.current?.getCenter().toJSON()}
                    >
                        <MapNav></MapNav>
                        {responseMarkers.map((marker) => {
                            return (
                                <Marker
                                    position={marker.position}
                                    key={marker.options.index}
                                    icon={marker.icon}
                                    zIndex={marker.zIndex}
                                    onClick={() => onMarkerClick(marker)}
                                ></Marker>
                            );
                        })}
                        {isInfoBoxOpen &&
                            selectedMarker &&
                            selectedMarker?.options?.type !== 'target' && (
                                <InfoBox
                                    options={{
                                        zIndex: 600,
                                        pixelOffset: new window.google.maps.Size(-100, 0)
                                    }}
                                    ref={infoBoxRef}
                                    onCloseClick={() => setIsInfoBoxOpen(!isInfoBoxOpen)}
                                    position={selectedMarker.position}
                                    zIndex={700}
                                >
                                    <InsInfoCard selectedMarker={selectedMarker}></InsInfoCard>
                                </InfoBox>
                            )}
                    </GoogleMap>
                </LoadScript>
            ) : (
                <h4 className="text-center m-12">
                    Tarayıcı versiyonunuz {version} güncel değildir.<br></br> Bu versiyon harita
                    görünümünü desteklememektedir.<br></br> Lüfen tarayıcınızı güncel bir versiyona
                    yükseltiniz.
                </h4>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default InsMap;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way I can get rid of this loading... text and I can show text like in here ==>

```html
                <h4 className="text-center m-12">
                    Tarayıcı versiyonunuz {version} güncel değildir.<br></br> Bu versiyon harita
                    görünümünü desteklememektedir.<br></br> Lüfen tarayıcınızı güncel bir versiyona
                    yükseltiniz.
                </h4>
```

Comment: Hi! Why would you want to make your app runnable in a slow internet or lower versions of chrome? There's no issue with the latest ones and with good internet right?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with the latest ones and good internet. It only stucks at lower Chrome versions or if the user has a slow internet speed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, what prevents your users from updating their chrome versions?

Comment: Basically they are not updating chrome or their PC s are lack out of modern hardwares.